# My handlebars template gets terminated automatically when rendering

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

I'm having a handlebar template defined. When rendered, a closing  tag is automatically added just before any closing tag in my template, which leads my template being considered as plain text.

If you check this page:
https://www.locaboat.com/tarifs/

ex.:
{{myVariable}} is displayed as {{myVariable}}

.

I've checked and I don't have any  tag left open.
Even weirder, if I add an antislash before the closing tag, it keeps on interpreting the handlebars correctly, but of course it's not displayed correctly

ex.:
{{myVariable}} is displayed as {{myVariable}}</div>

working on PHP Version 5.6.40, UTF-8 server

```js
<script id="offer-template-<?php echo $shortcode_id;?>" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 api-item date price" data-date="{{date}}" data-price="{{price}}" data-image="{{image}}" data-api-id="{{boat_id}}">
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-img-top"><img src="{{image}}"></div>
                <div class="discount"><span class="h-rounded">-{{percent_discount}}%</span></div>
            </div>
```

Right now, the output displays the rest of my handlebars template as plain text where it should be interpreted as a template, same as this page: https://www.locaboat.com/offres-speciales/

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the order in which dependencies are loading on the page. I don't see jQuery being imported in the source for this page at all, but it seems to be working. Perhaps it is coming in as a dependency of `kinetic` or another plugin. Anyway, you need to make sure it is imported *before* handlebars.

In your script tags, you are using `$` as an alias for `jQuery`, but if you open the console and type '$', you can see it is undefined (whereas, if you type 'jQuery' you get the function definition, as expected).

Since it seems that jQuery is otherwise working on the page, you might just need to replace this:

```
var offer_source = document.getElementById("offer-template-44").innerHTML;
```

with this:

```
var offer_source = $("#offer-template-44").html();
```

Or if that doesn't work, try [$.noConflict();](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

But it seems it's not working. I added jQuery in the head section, but in fact it was already there.

I tried to change the line you were talking about and also tried with a no-conflict.
Template is being read, but as soon as it has a closing tag, a </script> tag is added still.

Comment: Got it:  it looks like your `offer_source` closing `</script>` tag is in the wrong place.

Comment: Am sorry, not sure I'm following. I do have a </script> at the end of the whole JS part that contains the offer_source part :(

Comment: Take the closing tag at the end of this: `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="offer-template-44"><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 api-item date price" data-date="{{date}}" data-price="{{price}}" data-image="{{image}}" data-api-id="{{boat_id}}"><div class="card mb-4"><div class="card-header"><div class="card-img-top"><img src="{{image}}"></script>` and move it right before the next script tag: `<div style="display: none;"><span class="price" data-price="{{price}}">{{price}}</span><span class="date" data-date="{{date}}">{{date}}</span></div></div>` *HERE* `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Thanks again Ben, but this is actually my issue. I didn't place any </script> tag, it is, for some reason automatically added on the front when the page is displayed.

Comment: I finally understand the problem. Try building the multi-line HTML template with back-ticks (``), [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Alternately, you may be able to escape the slashes for the closing divs, like this: `<\/div>`